# IE6 PNG transparency in UpdatePanel

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel, png, internet-explorer-6

I have a child page with an UpdatePanel on it that is connected to a timer that autorefreshes every 5 seconds. I've tried a few different PNG fixes, and they work until the UpdatePanel refreshes that section. Then, depending on the fix the PNGs either disappear or go back to nontransparent. Do I need to forcefully run the javascript when the UpdatePanel refreshes? How would I go about this?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to stop using IE6. At least update to IE7.

Comment: Yea thanks, could you please let the company I work for know that.

Comment: @sensorium7 - Tell them to search google for "google drops ie6"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your using a JavaScript trick to get around IE 6's lack of png transparency, you need to register your script with the **ScriptManager** to run when the **UpdatePanel** refreshes.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, typeof(Page),
         UniqueID, "doSomething()", true);
}
```

[MSDN Reference](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.registerstartupscript.aspx)

Comment: Seems to have worked perfectly! Thanks for your help, spent wayy too long on that :)